# How do I tell a parent process to wait for a child process?

Tags: java, process

In my java code, I have the following lines

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("another program");
```

My understanding is this creates a child process.  Is there a way to execute "another program" using the parent process?  Or a way to tell the parent to wait until the execution is finished before continuing?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to execute "another program" using the parent process?

No, a separate process is required.

> ...or a way to tell the parent to wait until the execution is finished before continuing?

[`Process#waitFor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor--) does exactly that:

> Causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process represented by this `Process` object has terminated. This method returns immediately if the subprocess has already terminated. If the subprocess has not yet terminated, the calling thread will be blocked until the subprocess exits.

E.g.:

```
pr.waitFor();
```